# Cant covnert UTF-8 to UTF-16BE exporting csv says Its ANSI

Tags: php, csv, export, encode

So im trying to convert Spanish text from UTF-8 to UTF-16 but when i export the .csv file its says - ANSI, so the text is wrong on output here is the code sample

```
function convert_obj_to_UTF16($obj){
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-16", "utf-8");
    $obj[$key] = $value;
}

return $obj;
```

}

Comment: What is the output when setting **auto** instead of **utf-8** like this `$value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-16", "auto");`

Answer (score 0):

When the file was created, it was assigned the default encoding, try creating the same file, but when creating it, specify the encoding you need. Usually in editors, the file encoding is indicated in the lower right corner (vs code)